# Javascript Styles not applying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a Pure JS scroll to Top button. I'm writing a function to gather the window height and with, then write the appropriate margins to the scroll button, to keep it in a fixed position outside of the container(container is the 901 in marginx variable). However, when I load the page, the function isn't applying any of the margins to the "scroll" element, and I have no errors.

my code:

```
<head>
<script>
function displayScrollTop(){
    var w=window,
        d=document,
        e=d.documentElement,
        g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,
        y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;

    var marginy = 60-y; //margin-top value
    var marginx = "-" + (x-901)/2 - 60; 

    //image is floated right, this creates a negative margin left to pull to center.
           The width of the window - 901 (width of the container)/2 to get the side
           margins, - 60 (width of button) 


    document.getElementById('scroll').style.marginTop = marginy;
    document.getElementById('scroll').style.marginLeft = marginx;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="displayScrollTop();">
    <div id="scroll">
        <a onclick="scrollToTop(500);"><img src="images/scrolltotopbutton.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    </div>

</body>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify that the margin values are in `px`, by appending `"px"` to them.